# Count values in $_POST

Tags: php

I have the weirdest problem. I need to count how many values are submitted via $_POST in PHP.
I tried `count($_POST['posted'])` and I keep on getting 1 instead of 30+ expected values.

I checked if it is an array and yes it is! Tried; `print_r($_POST);` and get values

> Array( ['posted'] => asdasd asdasd ...
>   asdasd )

What am I missing?

---

UPDATE:

```
$count = count($_POST);
echo $count.' --- ';
print_r($_POST);
```

Output:

> 1 --- Array ( [posted] => asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd )

...and

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

produces:

> array(1) { ["posted"]=> string(152)
>   "asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd
>   asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd
>   asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd
>   asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd " }

and finally...

```
var_export($_POST);
```

delivers:

> array ( 'posted' => 'asdasd asdasd
>   asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd
>   asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd
>   asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd
>   asdasd asdasd ', )

Comment: Um, how about `count($_POST)`? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: count should work fine. Are the values nested?

Comment: gosh! post the exact output of the print_r! not that fake

Comment: @yes123 It is the output I get, except about 30 of those "asdasd"

Comment: Where $_POST['posted'] came from? It isn't an array, it is a string (try var_dump($_POST) and see). That's why count($_POST['posted']) is meaningless here.

Comment: I can't how the question is related to the update, or a new question in the update.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you're asking why `count()` doesn't deliver for each space-delimited "*asdasd*" in `$_POST['posted']`. See my answer, as it appears you want to `explode()` it and count the result.

Answer (score 5):

`$_POST` is always an array, but your `$_POST['posted']` isn't an array itself.

Answer (score 4):

To count the number of items in a `$_POST` array, use `count($_POST)` (not `count($_POST['posted']`))

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$my_count = count($_POST);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your form is posting the parameters as a nested array:

```
<input name="posted[]" />
```

Then your method should be correct. However based on your example, its a single string of space-separated values, so you'd want to:

```
$values = explode(' ', $_POST['posted']);
$count = count($values);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your form is posting multiple value for each parameter (posted) then you have to give name for this parameter as array in name attribute:

```html
<input name="posted[]" value="abc" />
<input name="posted[]" value="opq" />
<input name="posted[]" value="xyz" />
```

Once you posting this form you will get the count for **posted** variable as below:

```php
echo count($_POST['posted']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array must have been treated earlier but try `var_dum($_RESQUEST)` it will show you all the posted, url and cookies vars if in the request it's also like it is now it means your form input or any feild names have the same name lol or that you did a treatement

Answer (score -1):

```
$post = $_POST["posted"];        // get posted value
$total = (explode('', $post));   // separate values which have space 
$list = count($total);           // count separated values
echo $list;                      // Print count number
```