# How to Count number of POST variables

Tags: php, mysql

I have variables something like this:

```
 $id1 = $_POST['id1'];
 $id2 = $_POST['id2']; 
 $id3 = $_POST['id3'];
 $id4 = $_POST['id4'];
 $id5 = $_POST['id5'];
```

I have no idea that how many post variables are receiving, I have to count how many static post variables are here?

Comment: Why do you wanna do that? This looks like a XY problem. `count($_POST);` does it for you anyways. And if you submit with `name="id[]"`, that will make it an array for you.

Comment: `echo count($_POST);` ;)

Comment: Best to submit them as `id[]` and let PHP do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: can u please explain whats in your mind about static and dynamic $_POST?

Comment: please refer the similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431106/count-values-in-post)..

Comment: its i am getting $_POST form another places form android data and i have not idea how many post i'll get ,so variables are not static

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431106/count-values-in-post     i not able to find here correct answer !!

Comment: here count values in $_POST[ ] not a total count the variables !!

Comment: i don't get why this question has recieved so many down votes....

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$my_count = count($_POST);
echo $my_count;
```