# getting the number of arguments sent

Tags: php, html

My php file will recive one of two forms. One contains 2 inputs, the other contains one. Is there a way to get which one of the two was submited based on the number of arguments sent?

```
    <form action="a.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="firstA" />
    <input type="text" name="secondA" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" />
    </form>

    <form action="a.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="B" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" />
    </form>



<?php
  $number = "number of arguments" 
?>
```

Comment: try to count($_POST)

Comment: or use submit with submitbutton1 for 1st form and submitbutton2 for second

Comment: Why do you want to base it on the number of arguments rather than a hidden field/etc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count values in $\_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431106/count-values-in-post)

Comment: Create the buttons with different names `<input type="submit" name="submitbutton1" />` and `<input type="submit" name="submitbutton2" />` Then do an `isset($_POST['submitbutton1')` to check which form was submitted

Comment: "based on the number of arguments sent" - this sounds like the XY problem - better to determine the origin of the request based on a more definitive attribute as RigssFolly and VladimirKovpak suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd rather advice you to use `hidden` input for this purposes, like:

```
<form action="a.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="firstA" />
  <input type="text" name="secondA" />
  <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" />
  <input type="hidden" name="formName" value="formA" />
</form>

<form action="a.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="B" />
  <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" />
  <input type="hidden" name="formName" value="formB" />
</form>
```

And your php code will look like this:

```
if ($_POST['formName'] === 'formA') { handleFormA(); }
if ($_POST['formName'] === 'formB') { handleFormB(); }
```

But if you wish to rely on count of arguments you can to do something like:

```
if (count($_POST[]) === 3) { handleFormA(); }
if (count($_POST[]) === 1) { handleFormB(); }
```

Comment: Please don't try to control the program flow client-side

Comment: @Lithilion: Are you suggesting a new form of software development where the behaviour of a program is no longer determined by its inputs?

Comment: The addition of extra fields in a form is totally unnecessary and is more likely to lead to mistakes

Comment: No, I only say that you should consider someone changing the values of the hidden input

Answer (score 1):

That is a very dangerous way of deciding which form has been posted. What if in 3 months you geta request to add another field to the form with 2 fields. Then  they both have 3 fields.

All you need to do is give the button on each form a unique name like this

```
<form action="a.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="firstA" />
    <input type="text" name="secondA" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitbutton1" />
</form>

<form action="a.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="B" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitbutton2" />
</form>
```

Now in your PHP you can check for the existance of the button and you will know which form you are processing

```
<?php

    if ( isset($_POST['submitbutton1']) ) {
        // I am processing form 1
    }

    if ( isset($_POST['submitbutton2']) ) {
        // I am processing form 2
    }
```

Comment: Ahh silly me, small typo. I have fixed it now, take another look

Answer (score 0):

you can also try:

```
<form action="a.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="firstA" />
  <input type="text" name="secondA" />
  <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" />
  <input type="hidden" name="formAinputname" value="formA" />
</form>

<form action="a.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="B" />
  <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" />
  <input type="hidden" name="formBinputname" value="formB" />
</form>
```

you not need check hidden input value you can check by input name like below:

```
if( array_key_exists( 'formAinputname', $_POST ) )
{
  handleFormA();
}

if( array_key_exists( 'formBinputname', $_POST ) )
{
    handleFormB();
}
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as the answer from Vladimir

Comment: this is also another way.